# "too many arguments for public constructor string() defined " Kotlin problem

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, cursor

I'm a bit lost, make a database, where the user will have to save the results of the study, in which he will choose data from various widgets, such as spinners or RGs. How to encode variables of type Int or String is not a problem for me but in the case of Spinner number picker and RG already. Can somebody straighten me out?

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
    Package com.example.apkadlapacjenta

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_historia_pomiarow.*


class HistoriaPomiarow : AppCompatActivity() {

    var listaWynikow = ArrayList<FIrebaseVal>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_historia_pomiarow)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        //Wczytujemy baze danych
        LoadQuery("%")

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        LoadQuery("%")
    }

    private fun LoadQuery(title:String){
        val dbManager = DbMenager(this)
        val projections = arrayOf("Id", "Stezenie", "Zegar","Data","Posilek","Stres","Samopoczucie","Hiperglikemia","Insulina")
        val cursor =
            dbManager.Query(projections, "Title like?", selectionArgs   , "Title")
        listaWynikow.clear()
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ***val ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id"))      ---> HERE i have problem 
                val Stezenie = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Stezenie")) ---> NumberPicker 
                val Zegar = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Zegar"))
                val Data =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Data"))
                val Posilek = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Posilek")) -----> RB
                val Stres = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Stres"))
                val Samopoczucie = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Samopoczucie"))   --->SPINNER
                val Hiperglikemia = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Hiperglikemia"))--->SPINNER
                val Insulina = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Insulina"))       --->SPINNER
                **listaWynikow.add(Note(ID, Stezenie, Zegar,Data,Posilek,Stres,Samopoczucie,Hiperglikemia,Insulina))
            } while (cursor.moveToNext())*****
        }
    }

}
```

"---> Spinner,Numberpicker,RG" etc etc isnt CODE

DateBase Menager

```
    package com.example.apkadlapacjenta

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder
import android.widget.RadioGroup
import android.widget.Toast

class DatebaseMenagerPomiary {

    //Database name
    var dbName = "Historia Pomiarów"
    //table name
    var dbTable = "Wyniki"
    //kolumny
    var colID = "Id"
    var colStezenie = "Stezenie"
    var colZegar = "Zegar"
    var colData = "Data"
    var colPosilek = "Posilek"
    var colStres = "Stres"
    var colSamopoczucie = "Samopoczucie"
    var colHiperglikemia = "Hiperglikemia"
    var colInsulina = "Insulina"

    //wersja
    var dbVersion = 1

    //Tworzymy tabele
    val sqlCreateTable =
        "CREATE TABLE$dbTable($colID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $colStezenie NumberPicker, $colZegar TEXT, $colData TEXT, $colPosilek RADIO GROUP, $colStres SPINNER,$colSamopoczucie SPINNER, $colHiperglikemia SPINNER, $colInsulina TEXT)"

    var sqlDB: SQLiteDatabase? = null
    constructor(context: Context){
        var db = DatabaseHelperWyniki(context)
        sqlDB = db.writableDatabase
    }


     inner class DatabaseHelperWyniki : SQLiteOpenHelper {
        var context: Context? = null
         constructor(context: Context) : super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion) {
            this.context = context
        }

        override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
            db!!.execSQL(sqlCreateTable)
            Toast.makeText(this.context,"baza danych utworzona...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }

        override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
            db!!.execSQL("zamknij tabele jeśli nie istnieje" + dbTable)
        }


    }

    fun  insert(values:ContentValues):Long{
        val ID  = sqlDB!!.insert(dbTable,"",values)
        return ID
    }
    fun Query(projection:Array<String>,selection:String,selectionArgs:Array<String>,sorOrder:String): Cursor {

        val qb = SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        qb.tables=dbTable
        val cursor = qb.query(sqlDB,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sorOrder)
        return cursor
    }

    fun delete(selection: String,selectionArgs: Array<String>):Int{
        val count = sqlDB!!.delete(dbTable,selection,selectionArgs)
        return count
    }

    fun update(values:ContentValues,selection: String,selectionArgs: Array<String>): Int {
        val count = sqlDB!!.update(dbTable,values,selection,selectionArgs)
        return count
    }



}
```

NODE CLASS

```
NODE CLASS 

    package com.example.apkadlapacjenta

import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.NumberPicker
import android.widget.RadioGroup
import android.widget.Spinner

class FIrebaseVal(nodeID: Int, nodeNumberPicker:NumberPicker,nodezegar:String,nodedata:String,nodeposilek:RadioGroup,nodehiperglikemia:Spinner,nodestres:Spinner,nodesamopoczucie:Spinner,nodeinsulina:Int) {
    var nodeID: Int?= nodeID
    var nodeNumberPicker:NumberPicker?= nodeNumberPicker
    var nodezegar:String?=nodezegar
    var nodedata:String?=nodedata
    var nodeposilek:RadioGroup?=nodeposilek
    var nodehiperglikemia:Spinner?=nodehiperglikemia
    var nodestres:Spinner?=nodestres
    var nodesamopoczucie:Spinner?=nodesamopoczucie
    var nodeinsulina:Int?=nodeinsulina
}
```

The rest of the code I know how to do, i.e. the adapter and various functions such as `SearchView` etc, need help with Numberpicker, Spinner and RG encoding because in the line:

```
listaWynikow.add(Note(ID, Stezenie, Zegar,Data,Posilek,Stres,Samopoczucie,Hiperglikemia,Insulina))
            } while (cursor.moveToNext())
```

I get an error 
"too many arguments for public constructor string() defined ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with node class here you have declared total 9 parameter :

```
class FIrebaseVal(nodeID: Int, nodeNumberPicker:NumberPicker,nodezegar:String,nodedata:String,nodeposilek:RadioGroup,nodehiperglikemia:Spinner,nodestres:Spinner,nodesamopoczucie:Spinner,nodeinsulina:Int)
```

but here your passing 10 parameter please confirm the parameter values. I can't understand variable name.

```
listaWynikow.add(Note(ID, Stezenie, Zegar,Data,Posilek,Stres,Samopoczucie,Hiperglikemia,Insulina))
```